# Create nested XmlSchemaComplexType in XML schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I want to create an `xsd` file like [this](https://www.shpdata.com/xsd/CAHPSHospice.xsd).

I am using this

```
            XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
            schema.Id = "SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA";

            XmlSchemaElement elementData = new XmlSchemaElement();
            schema.Items.Add(elementData);
            elementData.Name = "SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA";


            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType = new XmlSchemaComplexType();
            elementData.SchemaType = complexType;// This is same as below. It's working fine but next is not working.

            XmlSchemaSequence sequence = new XmlSchemaSequence();
            complexType.Particle = sequence;

            // here some elements

            XmlSchemaElement surveydataEle = new XmlSchemaElement();
            sequence.Items.Add(surveydataEle);
            surveydataEle.Name = "CAHPS_HOSPICE_SURVEY_DATA";
            surveydataEle.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            surveydataEle.MinOccurs = 1;
            surveydataEle.MaxOccurs = 2000;

            XmlSchemaComplexType complexType1 = new XmlSchemaComplexType();
            surveydataEle.SchemaType = complexType1;

            XmlSchemaSequence sequence1 = new XmlSchemaSequence();
            complexType1.Particle = sequence1;

            Type type = patient.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                string name = property.Name;
                XmlSchemaElement element = new XmlSchemaElement();
                sequence1.Items.Add(element);
                element.Name = name;
                element.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
                element.MinOccurs = 0;
            }

            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            schemaSet.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallbackOne);
            schemaSet.Add(schema);
            schemaSet.Compile();

            XmlSchema compiledSchema = null;

            foreach (XmlSchema schema1 in schemaSet.Schemas())
            {
                compiledSchema = schema1;
            }
            Random r = new Random();
            int random = r.Next();
            string filePath = "D:\\" + random + ".xsd";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
            }
            //Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, new UTF8Encoding());
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
            compiledSchema.Write(writer, nsmgr); // Exception is occurring here 
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
```

This is not working fine. 
An exception `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` occurred  at `compiledSchema.Write(writer, nsmgr);`

When I am not using second `XmlSchemaComplexType` then 
it's working fine. Here I am using same to same way to add `XmlSchemaComplexType` which is I am using fist but second time it's not working.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NullReferenceException` is being thrown because `compiledSchema` is null, which is because `schemaSet.Schemas()` is an empty collection, which is because `schemaSet.Add(schema)` fails, which is because your schema is broken.

The reason your schema is broken is that you are declaring `CAHPS_HOSPICE_SURVEY_DATA` to be both a string and a complex type, as one can see by dumping the XML from your `schema` variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="SHP_CAHPS_HOSPICE_DATA">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2000" name="CAHPS_HOSPICE_SURVEY_DATA" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
```

You declare it to be a string here using [`SchemaTypeName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.schematypename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        surveydataEle.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

You then declare it to be a complex type here using [`SchemaType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaelement.schematype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
        surveydataEle.SchemaType = complexType1;
```

The fix is to delete the first declaration:

```
        XmlSchemaElement surveydataEle = new XmlSchemaElement();
        sequence.Items.Add(surveydataEle);
        surveydataEle.Name = "CAHPS_HOSPICE_SURVEY_DATA";
        // surveydataEle.SchemaTypeName = new XmlQualifiedName("string", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");  <-- Deleted this line.
        surveydataEle.MinOccurs = 1;
        surveydataEle.MaxOccurs = 2000;

        XmlSchemaComplexType complexType1 = new XmlSchemaComplexType();
        surveydataEle.SchemaType = complexType1;
```